# Anchor link in Bootstrap 3.7 not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
    <ul style="font-family:'Ralway', Serif;" class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li><a href="http://www.reachoutcelebration.com/#home">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.reachoutcelebration.com/#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.reachoutcelebration.com/#events">EVENTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.reachoutcelebration.com/#surrenderstories">SURRENDER STORIES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.reachoutcelebration.com/#globalstrategy" >GLOBAL STRATEGY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.reachoutcelebration.com/#contact-form">CONTACT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/#donate">DONATE</a></li>
                </ul>
```

I want to click on "donate" or "contact" links that are from the reachoutcelebration.com/tommy-barnett page and go to the "donate" or "contact" section of this webpage: http://www.reachoutcelebration.com. PLEASE ONLY CLICK THE CONTACT AND DONATE BUTTONS. I have verified they do not work. Clicking donate and contact it seemed to throw me in the middle of the http://www.reachoutcelebration.com site no matter where I but the anchor tags or the id attributes. The above code is revised.

The code on the reachoutcelebration.com page reads as follows:

```
<!-- Section Header -->
        <div class="section-header container-fluid"><a name="donate"></a><!-- SEE ANCHOR HERE -->
            <h3>GRAND TOTAL : $521,000</h3>
            <div class="section-separator"><i class="fa fa-stop"></i></div>
            <p style="text-align:center;">"Multiply" begins with you.</br>Own a piece of the ROC and join us in reaching our city, our region, and our world.</p>
        </div><!-- Section Header /- -->
```

I already tried Expression Engine Stack over flow:
https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/38480/expression-engine-and-anchor-tags/38481#38481

Any ideas as to why it not working?

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my computer. Both the "contact" and "donate" links bring me to the correct section.

Comment: seems to work fine manually changing hash in url then reloading page to double check. Tested in firefox

Comment: I need you both click the "contact" and "donate" from the http://www.reachoutcelebration.com/tommy-barnett page, NOT the http://www.reachoutcelebration.com page. Then you'll see what I mean.  MY FAULT for the lack of clarity!

Comment: a couple of them worked fine. My guess is you have some ajax loading some of the content. Without code posted here have no intention of trying to poke through your files to figure out what is what. Without a [mcve] posted here you won't get much help

Comment: I re-posted with less code. If you go the website of reachoutcelebration.com/tommy-barnett and click the "donate" and "contact" buttons on the menu you'll easily see what I mean. Is there anything else I need to do to to make this more clear?

Comment: I clicked on the Contact link of the first page and was brought to the Contact section of the second page.  I reloaded the first page and clicked on its Donate link, and was taken to the Donate section of the second page.  This seems correct to me.  Chrome on Linux.  What exactly doesn't work for you?  What, specifically, do you see instead of whatever it is you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you have to do is match names and URL's for `<a name="donate"></a>` and `<a name="contact"></a>` respectively:

```
<li><a href="http://www.reachoutcelebration.com/#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.reachoutcelebration.com/#donate">DONATE</a></li>
```

Comment: tried that, it doesn't work. It appears to be positioning. Do you think its JS related?

Comment: You have the name defined as `<a name="contactus">` in the target page. Change it to `<a name="contact">` (or change the source link anchor to `.../#contactus`)

Answer (score 0):

After much stress and tinkering, the anchors work, but I have to put them in ackward positions at the bottom of the viewport to "kinda" "sorta" go where I want them to go. It works, but it's cumbersome. Not sure what else to do here. guess we can close this.

FYI, the anchor tags I used just have the `name` in it, hence `<a name="donate">` or `<a name="contactus">`

Comment: the `name` tag is no longer supported for anchoring in HTML5

Answer (score -1):

Add `id` attr to the `div` and test and it should work. I saw that anchor tag for donate has the `href` pointing to `#donate` but I think there's no div or section on the page with `id` `donate`.

```
       <!-- donate id added to this div -->
        <div class="section-header container-fluid" id="donate"><a name="donate"></a><!-- SEE ANCHOR HERE -->
            <h3>GRAND TOTAL : $521,000</h3>
            <div class="section-separator"><i class="fa fa-stop"></i></div>
            <p style="text-align:center;">"Multiply" begins with you.</br>Own a piece of the ROC and join us in reaching our city, our region, and our world.</p>
        </div><!-- Section Header /- -->
```

Comment: tried that too, still doesn't work. It appears to be positioning. Do you think its JS related? Be advised, the home page (reachoutcelebration.com) ALL works fine. ITs when you click the contact link from the reachoutcelebration.com/tommy-barnett page that it throws you in too far above the section. It's essentially seeing the bookmark/anchor and placing the it at the bottom of the viewport. Moving the anchor down doesn't help. VERY annoying.

Comment: I checked your website now and clicked on donate link at the top and it did land me directly on the donate section. It seems to work fine.

Comment: After much stress and tinkering, the anchors work, but I have to put them in ackward positions at the bottom of the viewport to "kinda" "sorta" go where I want them to go. It works, but it's cumbersome. Not sure what else to do here. guess we can close this.

FYI, the anchor tags I used just have the `name` in it, hence `<a name="donate">` or `<a name="contactus">`